# Process Builder - Last Modified date

Tags: process-builder

I was going through the existing Process builder (by other developers) and found a criteria condition -( Last Modified Date  - Is Changed -False ) ANDED with other conditions. I am not sure when this condition would evaluate to true as I though proces builder are fired when user tries to save the records. Please clear my understanding.